# how to write text to a file in .net for windows store.. for crying out loud

Tags: .net, file-io, windows-store-apps, streamwriter

I have a list of strings.

I want to output them to a txt file.

Very simple in .net traditionally, even done with a single line of code.

However with .net for windows store:

File.writeAllLines - doesnt work
using streamwriter - doesnt work

for crying out loud. please. somebody. help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest ways:

```
var myFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("myFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(myFile, "string content");
```